# Ideapad 320 stuck while updating 1703 to 1709

Tags: windows-10, updates

While updating from Windows 10 1703 to 1709, my Ideapad 320 says:

> "Working on updates 54%. Don't turn off your PC. This will take a while. Your PC will restart several times."

But it won't get past 54%.

How to stop working on updates?

Answer (score 1):

*All right:*

I had this issue while ago and i fixed it with just **turning off the pc**, 
i know its not recommendable but it might help your system roll out of that bump

**The cause**

It could be that your PC encountered a problem with the software already instaled or some other preexisting issue that just appeared right as windows started updating, sometimes its just the update itself that is causing the problem.

**Check if your Update is actualy stuck**

Windows updates are essential but they can take your time some of those updates can only take a few minutes others not so much and might take over 3 hours to complete
If you feel like its stuck for more than 3 hours check your HD Light of your case, just to see if its blinking (to see if theres any activity going on in your Hard Drive) if its not blinking at all, your pc its probably stuck.

**How to fix it?**

1. **Ctrl+Alt+Del**
   Windows update might me stuck in some part of your installation process,   if you press this command you could be presented with your windows login screen after executing the Ctrl+Alt+Del command.
2. **Turn OFf your PC**
   By pressing the reset button of your PC or just holding the power button (hard reboot) after that inmediatly turn on your PC to make sure your  PC is unstuck and works fine by now.
3. **Start Windows in Safe Mode**
   If windows does not load after that hard reboot, you can try Windows in Safe Mode. This special diagnostic mode of Windows only loads the minimum drivers and services that Windows absolutely needs, so if another program or service is conflicting with one of the Windows updates, the install might finish up just fine.

   If the Windows updates do install successfully and you continue to Safe Mode, just restart from there to enter Windows normally.
4. **Complete a System Restore**
   to undo the changes made so far by the incomplete installation of the Windows updates. Since you can't access Windows normally, try doing this from Safe Mode. See the link in Step 3 if you're not sure how to start in Safe Mode.

   **Note**: During the System Restore, be sure to choose the restore point created by Windows just prior to the update installation.
5. **Try System Restore from Advanced Startup Options**
   ...or System Recovery Options (Windows 7 & Vista) if you're not able to access Safe Mode or if the restore failed from Safe Mode. Since these menus of tools are available from "outside" of Windows, you can try this even if Windows is completely unavailable.
6. **Start your computer's "automatic" repair process**
   While a System Restore is a more direct way of undoing changes, in this case of a Windows update, sometimes a more comprehensive repair process is in order.

   In Windows 10 and Windows 8, try a Startup Repair. If that doesn't do the trick, try the Reset This PC process (the non-destructive option, of course).

   In Windows 7 and Windows Vista, try the Startup Repair process.
7. **Test your computer's memory**
   It's possible that failing RAM could be causing the patch installations to freeze. Fortunately, memory is really easy to test. You could also try and clean the pins of the RAM with an eraser.
8. **Update BIOS**
   An outdated BIOS isn't a common cause for this problem, but it's possible.

   If one or more of the updates Windows is trying to install is involved with how Windows works with your motherboard or other built-in hardware, a BIOS update could solve the issue.
9. **Clean install Windows**
   A clean install involves completely erasing the hard drive that Windows is installed on and then installing Windows again from scratch on that same hard drive.
   Obviously you don't want to do this if you don't have to, but it's a very likely fix if the troubleshooting steps prior to this one were unsuccessful.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

[Link to the article](https://www.lifewire.com/when-windows-update-gets-stuck-or-frozen-2624439)

Comment: Good to know, im going to edit it right now
i linked this because it worked for me to fix like 5 pcs in my work 
Thanks !!!